# How to use which command in Crontab?

Tags: shell-script, cron, non-root-user, which

I would like to make crontab run this script as a regular user:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PIDFILE=wp-content/uploads/sphinx/var/log/searchd.pid


if ! test -f ${PIDFILE} || ! kill -s 0 `cat ${PIDFILE}`; then
    `which searchd` --config /home/user/www/wordpress-page/wp-content/uploads/sphinx/sphinx.conf
fi
```

It simply reruns Sphinx Search daemon, because my shared server kills all my daemons if anything exceeds 1GB of ram (its Webfaction).

When I call that script by hand via CLI command it works, but if I attach it in crontab (using `crontab -e`) I got an email with an error

```
which: no searchd in (/usr/bin:/bin)
/home/user/www/wordpress-page/run-searchd.sh: line 8: --config: command not found
```

Simply which searches root level, but I would like it to behave as called by myself when I log in via ssh as regular user. How to make that happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because of the `$PATH`. Do this in your shell outside of `crontab`:

```
command -v searchd | xargs dirname
```

This command will return a directory where `searchd` is on your system or an error if you don't have `searchd` in your `$PATH` even in an interactive shell.  Now do this at the top of your script you execute in `crontab`:

```
 PATH=<directory_from_above_command>:$PATH
```

Alternatively just use a full path to `searchd` instead of `which searchd`.

Also read this on `which` if you want to fully understand how it works: [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then).

Answer (score 1):

Just use `searchid` directly.  If `which` can find it, it's in your `$PATH` already, so there's no need to use `which` here.

If you want to be sure to be able to execute it, use the utility with its full absolute path.

See also the question [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then) (about `which` in general).